# fileName to retrieve multiple file names

Tags: apache-camel

How do I get apache camel to fetch multiple files using `fileName` on the file component.  Here is my route:

`sftp://ftpserver:22/?username=blah&password=blah&stepwise=false&useList=false&ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=true&fileName=${file:onlyname.noext}.txt&delete=true&doneFileName=done")`

The files that are on the ftp server are `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`. How do I retrieve all of them without having to do a fixed `fileName` such as `fileName=3.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Simple expression language](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) in the `fileName` to provide a name pattern. There are some examples on the older documentation page http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html

In your case it should be sufficient to use `fileName=*.txt`.

Comment: added this route -> sftp://myftp.com:22/?username=test&password=test&fileName=*.txt.&delete=true&doneFileName=done -> and it doesn't work.  Seems like I can't get it to work unless it's a fixed string.  The sftp server gives me an error when camel does a list of the directory which is why I'm trying to give it a list of fixed file names.

Comment: @user301693 you are right, I was thinking about a special case where I used simple language for a complex dynamic filename. @Peter has the correct answer, you have to use `include` with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `include` option such as:

```
include=.*\\.txt
```

`include` uses Java regular expression.

Alternatively, you may use `antInclude`:

```
antInclude=*.txt
```

**EDIT:**

`antInclude` may contain more than one file name:

```
antInclude=1.txt,2.txt
```

(At least this works for local files.)

**EDIT:**

If you are not permitted to list on the FTP server, then you must setup a route for every single file:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    from("sftp://ftpserver:22/?fileName=${file:onlyname.noext}."+i+".txt")
        ...;
}
```

However, depending on the the number of files, this is not really something I would like to do..

Comment: This is more or less a filter after the ftp call does a list on the directory.  I'm trying to avoid doing a list because I don't have permission.  Trying to tell sftp to ONLY look for these set of files.

Comment: If filtering is not OK, then you need to specify every single file name, I guess.

Comment: I guess my question is how do I do that?  you can't really do -> fileName=1.txt,2.txt,3.txt etc...   I've also noticed that you can't do -> fileName=*.txt ->  any ideas?

Comment: @user301693 Perhaps you may use `antInclude=1.txt,2.txt`. However, I couldn't test it as I haven't a FTP server at hand.

Comment: tried -> antInclude=1.txt,2.txt  and it works with selecting just those txt files but ftp still does a list on the directory.  Would be nice If I could tell camel here is a SET of files and only look for them without having to do a list.  i.e. fileName=1.txt,2.txt etc...

Comment: @user301693 I added an alternative solution using a for-loop